# Formatting data for building stacked bars in recharts React

Tags: reactjs, lodash, recharts, stacked-bar-chart

My problem is to the best way to format the received data to build a custom [**recharts**](https://recharts.org/en-US/) stacked barchart.

I need to format the data by group_by field and for each Xaxis key (*usage_date* field) showing the data in such way as on the image:

[image]

Tried a lot of ways but suddenly they were unsuccessful.

The example of data that needs to be formatted for one Xaxis (*usage_date* field):

```
{
    "group_by": "Amazon Route 53",
    "usage_date": "2022-09-01",
    "account_id": "111",
    "service_name": "Amazon Route 53",
    "total_cost": 0.50038,
    "total_usage_quantity": 111,
    "resource_name": "",
    "resource_id": ""
},
{
    "group_by": "AWS Key Management Service",
    "usage_date": "2022-09-01",
    "account_id": "111",
    "service_name": "Amazon Route 53",
    "total_cost": 0.50038,
    "total_usage_quantity": 111,
    "resource_name": "",
    "resource_id": ""
},
{
    "group_by": "AWS Support [Business]",
    "usage_date": "2022-09-01",
    "account_id": "111",
    "service_name": "Amazon Route 53",
    "total_cost": 0.50038,
    "total_usage_quantity": 111,
    "resource_name": "",
    "resource_id": ""
},
{
    "group_by": "AWS Secrets Manager",
    "usage_date": "2022-09-01",
    "account_id": "111",
    "service_name": "Amazon Route 53",
    "total_cost": 0.50038,
    "total_usage_quantity": 111,
    "resource_name": "",
    "resource_id": ""
}
```

The React code for BarChart:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={500}>
  <BarChart data={barChartData} barCategoryGap="28%">
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" strokeOpacity={0.3} />
      <XAxis fontSize={11} />
      <YAxis fontSize={11} />
      <Tooltip />
  </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Thanks everybody for providing any help!

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to do this:

```
 const groupBy = (data) => {
  return _.chain(data)
    .groupBy("group_by")
    .map((value, key) => ({
      key: key,
      usage_date: value[0].usage_date,
      total_cost: _.sumBy(value, "total_cost"),
    }))
    .value();
};
```